# Wrong column data types when using dtswizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017, migration

I need to copy a database from a MS SQL Server 2017 to a MS SQL Server 2012.
I am not sure what's the best way to go, but I'm currently trying to use dtswizard to do the job.

Everything seems to be pretty ok, but when checking the column mappings, I see that all `money` fields are to be converted to `smallmoney` fields and all `nvarchar(xxx)` fields are to be converted `date` fields (and several more mismatches).

I could change the mappings manually, but there are hundreds of tables with each dozends of columns and that will both be a PITA and quite error-prone...

Is this a know issue?
Am I doing something wrong here?
Is there a workaround?

I am using the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server as data source for both the source and the target data source.

Comment: Is dtswizard the actual Import/Export tool that you find in SSMS? Do you see this just during the mapping? Or have you tried to see the result? What is the result of converting nvarchar to date? It should give an error, right?

Comment: Yes, it gives an error.
And yes, dtswizard is the Import/Export tool that comes with SQL Server.